# How to initialize QJsonObject from QString

Tags: c++, json, qt

I am quite new to Qt and I have a very simple operation that I want to do: 
I have to obtain the following JSonObject:

```
{
    "Record1" : "830957 ",
    "Properties" :
    [{
            "Corporate ID" : "3859043 ",
            "Name" : "John Doe ",
            "Function" : "Power Speaker ",
            "Bonus Points" : ["10 ", "45", "56 ", "34", "56", "10 ", "45", "56 ", "34", "56", "10 ", "45", "56 ", "34", "56", "10 ", "45", "56 ", "34", "56", "10 ", "45", "56 ", "34", "56 ", "10", "45 ", "56", "34 ", "56", "45"]
        }
    ]
}
```

The JSon was checked with this Syntax and Validity checker: http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ and was found valid.

I used QJsonValue initialization of String for that and converted it to QJSonObject:

```
QJsonObject ObjectFromString(const QString& in)
{
    QJsonValue val(in);
    return val.toObject();
}
```

I am loading the JSon pasted up from a file:

```
QString path = "C:/Temp";
QFile *file = new QFile(path + "/" + "Input.txt");
file->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QFile::Text);
QTextStream in(file);
QString text = in.readAll();
file->close();

qDebug() << text;
QJsonObject obj = ObjectFromString(text);
qDebug() <<obj;
```

There's most certainly a good way to do this because this is not working, and I didn't find any helpful examples

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Use [QJsonDocument::fromJson](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qjsondocument.html#fromJson)

```
QString data; // assume this holds the json string

QJsonDocument doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(data.toUtf8());
```

If you want the [QJsonObject](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qjsondocument.html#object)...

```
QJsonObject ObjectFromString(const QString& in)
{
    QJsonObject obj;

    QJsonDocument doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(in.toUtf8());

    // check validity of the document
    if(!doc.isNull())
    {
        if(doc.isObject())
        {
            obj = doc.object();        
        }
        else
        {
            qDebug() << "Document is not an object" << endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "Invalid JSON...\n" << in << endl;
    }

    return obj;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint @Merlin069 ! I guess this is the way to make the conversion but so far the doc fails the check and the whole function returns an empty un-initialized object. Did you try the function ?

Comment: If it's failing to find the document as an object, then the input string is not formatted correctly according to JSON.

Comment: According to [this format checher](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) it is valid.

Comment: Check the validity of the document after calling fromBinaryData; I've updated the answer to include this.

Comment: Thanks Merlin069. I've already seen that the document is null. The given example is a valid piece of JSON string... So I'll give you a +1 for your effort but unfortunately this still doesn't help.. If you have any time try to just paste the JSON in a text file, load it in a string and check the function.

Comment: Use QJsonDocument::fromJson, not fromBinaryData - updated answer

Comment: Hmmm... when I try to enter this into xcode, I get the type error "Incomplete type 'QJsonDoncument' named in nested name specifier." what is that about?

Comment: @EthanKeller, check your spelling of QJsonDocument !

Comment: @TheDarkKnight Haha. whoops... Thanks. Words are hard!

Answer (score 5):

You have to follow this step

1. convert Qstring to QByteArray first
2. convert QByteArray to QJsonDocument
3. convert QJsonDocument to QJsonObject

```
QString str = "{\"name\" : \"John\" }";

QByteArray br = str.toUtf8();

QJsonDocument doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(br);

QJsonObject obj = doc.object();

QString name = obj["name"].toString();
qDebug() << name;
```